# Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1175648978, epoch=189) to node 53: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException

Tags: java, kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have a topic with 100 partitions and the load is millions of records per hour. 
We ran into the problem whenever we deploy a new version of stream-processor using state-store with stateful-set in Kubernetes.

Normally, we need 4 pods to handle the workload of 100  partitions. 
Before deploying a new version,
4 instances are up to date with the data from the topics.
Three out of 4 times when we deploy a new version, only 2 or 3 instances are processing the data within a minutes, the others throw exception:

```
 Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1175648978, epoch=189) to node 53: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException
```

So all the data in the partitions that assigned to instance # 4 are build up and the lag is increasing...

If we scale the number of instances to 6 or 8, then  5 or 6 instances are processing the data, other 3 or 2 instances throw
this exception:

```
 Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1175648978, epoch=189) to node 53: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException
```

If we let all the instances run like that, eventually ( some between 4 to 36 hours later ) all the instances will be fine and no more exception from any pod.

Any suggestions to fix this problem be appreciated.

Thanks,

Austin

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, it sounds like you have some connectivity issues.  Can you include some broker side logs and streams application logs covering the time period?

Comment: Do you still have this problem or have you solved it already ?
Was bbejeck right and it was a connectivity problem ?

Comment: do you fix this? i'm facing same problem and after that stream thread dead. because ot this, i can not restore state store :(  @AustinTX

Comment: Any fix on this?